# Удалились локальные файлы с remote ветки git

Tags: javascript, git, github, visual-studio-code, git-branch

Работаю в VScode, при change изменения я решил проверить на какой ветке я нахожусь, оказался в origin/master, не подумал, переключился обратно на свою основную ветку, и все изменения, которые я делал, пропали. Переключился обратно на remote ветку, но оттуда изменения тоже пропали. Куда подевались мои файлы? Делал долго, на протяжении недели, поэтому переписывать заново желания нет.

Comment: А как переключались? обычно вроде сохраняются

Comment: команда ```git log``` поможет найти свои коммиты